# Using VBA to list folders and properties(date last modified)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Code listed below that lists all the folder names in a parent folder. I am trying to additionally list the folder properties in particular, 'Date Last Modified'. I know this is possible for files in a folder, but in this case, its the folders that I need this for.

I tried using FileSystemObject but I'm having problems with it not sure if my original code is the issue.

Can someone help me with direction as to what I can do next.

Here is my original code:

```
Sub GetFolders()
Dim path As String
Dim folder As String
Dim row As Integer


path = "\\C:bla bla\"
folder = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
row = 1

Do While folder <> ""
If (GetAttr(path & folder) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
    Cells(row, 1) = path & folder
    row = row + 1
End If
folder = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileDateTime()` can do this.

Inside the loop:

```
Cells(row, 1) = path & folder
If (folder <> "." And folder <> "..") Then
    Cells(row, 2) = FileDateTime(path & folder)
End If
row = row + 1
```